# Instanciate a ViewModel when app start

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm creating an application using MVVMLight.

In my app I have a "Catalog" view and a `Downloads` view each one associated with it's own ViewModel which are declared in the `ViewModelLocator` :

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CatalogViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CreatorViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DownloadsViewModel>();
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotifyUserMethod);
    }


    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public CatalogViewModel Catalog
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CatalogViewModel>();
        }
    }  

    public DownloadsViewModel Downloads
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DownloadsViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public CreatorViewModel Creator
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CreatorViewModel>();
        }
    }      

    private void NotifyUserMethod(NotificationMessage message )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels

    }



}
```

I planned to use messaging to send my `selectedCatalogItems` to a collection in the downloads VM, but it does only work if the user has first opened the download view. In the other case the Download view model isn't yet created and the the message goes nowhere.

Is there's a way to call the constructor of the Downdload VM at app startup or Should I use a dedicated class to store my download list ?

Comment: You could also register an instance of the view model for the lifetime of the app. that way when you call get instance you get the same view model every time.

Comment: Sounds great ! Do you have any advice on how to achieve that ? As I rely on mvvm light which handles the view models instanciation I can't figure out where and how I should call my view model's constructor.

Comment: Same place when you register the other viewmodels. does the viewmodel locator have a static constructor? your snippet is rather disjointed so cannot tell

Comment: Here's the constructor of my Locator, same as default from mvvm light so it's not static :  public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CatalogViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DownloadsViewModel>();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an instance of the view model early in the lifetime of the application as the service locator will hold on to an instance of it in its cache.

```
public class ViewModelLocator {
    static ViewModelLocator() {

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CatalogViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CreatorViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DownloadsViewModel>();

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        //Default instance
        //Done so an instance will be generated and held in cache
        var defaultDownloadsViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DownloadsViewModel>();
    }

    public ViewModelLocator(){
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotifyUserMethod);
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public CatalogViewModel Catalog
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CatalogViewModel>();
        }
    }  

    public DownloadsViewModel Downloads
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DownloadsViewModel>();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyUserMethod(NotificationMessage message )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels

    }
}
```